# How to make a progress bar when uploading to Vimeo

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vimeo-api

I'm using the package  [vinkla/vimeo](https://github.com/vinkla/vimeo) inside a laravel app

The process to upload the video is working with this code:

```
 $upload = Vimeo::upload($request->file('file'));
```

I need to give some information to a user that is uploading, perhaps a progress bar.

But i have no clue how to build that.

The oficial documentation says: 
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#verify-the-upload

> To check how much of a file has transferred, perform the exact same
>   PUT request without the file data and with the header "Content-Range:
>   bytes */*". Here’s an example request:

`PUT https://1234.cloud.vimeo.com/upload?ticket_id=abcdef124567890
Host: 1.2.3.4:8080
Content-Length: 0
Content-Range: bytes */*`

If anyone can give me some tip or a link that i can learn how to make it happen, would be awesome.

Comment: If you'd like, I can explain the process (which I just figured out...) by using: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib

Comment: Yes, i would appreciate you can explain how this works. Thank you .)

Comment: I'd be happy to do so.  Can you show me what you've done so far (i.e. some code) using vimeo-php-lib so I can see where you are in the process?

Comment: What i have is:
Controller:

`$lib = new Vimeo(env('VIMEO_CLIENT_ID'), env('VIMEO_SECRETS'), env('VIMEO_TOKEN'));
$request = $lib->request('/me/videos', ['redirect_url' => 'http:...'], 'POST');
$ticket = $request['body']['upload_link_secure'];
return view('dashboard.videos.upload', compact('ticket'));`

View:
`<form method="POST" action="{{ $ticket }}" ...>
<input name="file" type="file" multiple/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>`

But probably i have to make a PUT ajax request with the file instead and after that check the progress?

Comment: Yes.  You'll need to perform an ajax request to check the progress every x seconds. If you use the _request method from the library and use: $curl_opts_check_progress = array(
            CURLOPT_PUT => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Length: 0', 'Content-Range: bytes */*')
        );  as well as your 'upload_link_secure' as the $url, then  _request($url, $curl_opts_check_progress) will return the amount that has been uploaded.

Comment: Thank you, for your help. :) 
I think i'm almost there. How can i access to the _request method if it is private, from my controller/method? Or i should use the request method like following: 
`->request($this->ticket, $curl_opts_check_progress, 'PUT')`
What is your suggestion?
Sorry but i'am really a newbie xD

Comment: Not at all!  It took me several days to figure this all out.  Anyway, what I did (and I should have told you this...) is I extended the Vimeo method: class My_Vimeo extends \Vimeo\Vimeo and just copied the same exact _request method from Vimeo in addition to my new checkProgress method (as descried above) in the extended class.  This way I had access to all of the Vimeo methods (including its _request method) in addition to my new method.

Comment: Well thought, you gave me a big help. :)  How you upload the video itself? you use a upload method in the library or you make a from POST to upload_link_secure? Because if you use the upload method he generate a ticket and you need that ticket to check the progress in the _request.
Thanks again :)

Comment: I *think* that I understand your question.  And, if I do, what I've done is use the upload method from the library, and then I save the ticket to my database and associate it with a unique token.  The token is then saved in a session and I query the database for the upload_upload_link secure based on the the session. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, this help me a lot. Don't know how thank you... :)

Comment: No worries! I hope that this thread can help out other people as well.